# Create NSDictionary file in windows(c#)?

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

My iphone app creates files using the my custom ".ops" extension. using NSDictionary. Nsdictionary goes like this:

```
nsdictionary = nsdictionary withObjectsForKeys:
nameField.text , @"name", 
descField.text, @"description", 
author.text, @"author", 
ItemArray, @"values", nil; 
//ItemArrays objects are strings: @"red", @"blue", @"green";
```

I use writeToFile to save the nsdictionary to "name.ops" in the DocumnetLibrary.
However I wonder if using C#, I could make the same file(name.ops) with the same properties(name, desc etc) and the strings array and extension and still be able to import and open that file in my iphone app?

Well I want to make the same app in the windows platform too. Since creating a new .ops file in the iphone small screen is hard. So I want to make it simple to create ops files!

How could I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so your .ops files are plists with a custom extension?

plists are xml files. You should be able to create them in every language you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>key 1</key>
    <string>value 1</string>
    <key>key 2</key>
    <true/>
    <key>key 3</key>
    <integer>12</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Open one of your .ops files with TextEdit and see how they look like.

Comment: wow that was nice! thanx! :D Do you know how I could find the files in the documentsDirectory? im using the simulator right now!

Comment: from the log: File saved in: /Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/53EE7741-9FCB-4259-AA0B-4B93AFDF9A9A/Documents/myFirstOps.ops      But finder doesnt find it. how Could I open it?

Comment: have you checked the returned BOOL of writeToFile:atomically:? Maybe the file save wasn't successful. If you just can't find the folder, open Finder, select Go in the Menubar, Go To Folder and paste /Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/53EE7741-9FCB-4259-AA0B-4B93AFDF9A9A/Documents/ in the box that opens

Comment: the problem was that those files were hidden! using ThinkerTool I disabled "hide system files". And tHen I found it! I opened the plist and it look so orgnized I can even see the arrays strings there! Thank you very much mate! You made my day:D